# Styling classes and images within the class

Tags: css, class

Below is my code to style a web page. I am really finding it difficult to style left and right classes next to each other as the images take up the entire space. I have attached the image of the required final output. Can someone please help.I have the html code as well but I am not suppose to make any changes to it.

```
header {

      background-color : #ffbd80;
      background-image : url(../images/flywheel.jpg);
      background-size: cover;
      padding: 25px;
 }

 h1{
     color: #ffffff;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform : uppercase;
     font-size : 175%;
 }
 h2{
      color: #000000;
      text-transform : uppercase;
 }

 body{
     padding : 20pxpx;
     margin : 15px;
 }

 section {
       background-color: #ffa550;

 }

 nav a{
    opacity: 0.7;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    width : 22%;
    display :inline-block;
    text-decoration : none;
    padding : 5px;
    border-radius : 10px;

 }

 .active
     { background-color:#808080;
     color: #0000ff;}





    enter code here

 }

 .left{
     float: left;
     width: 20 %;
     display : inline-block;
     border : 1px solid;
     border-width : 3px;
     clear: both ;

 }

 .left a{

    display: inline-block;
    width: 2%

    margin-left: 20 %;
    margin-top: 20 %;
}


 }
 .right 
 {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 70%;

     float: right;
 }

main {
    display: inline-block;
}

 /*img{
    display: none 
 }
 .left a{

    display: none;
    margin-left: 20 %;
    margin-top: 20 %;
}
```

I am not suppose to make any changes to the HTML code 
The html code is below: [image: the page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Ultimate Frisbee - History</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hw1.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Ulimate Frisbee History</h1>
        <nav >
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="teams.html">Teams</a>
            <a href="history.html" class = "active">History</a>
            <a href="http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html" target="_blank">USA Ultimate</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
        <main>
            <aside class = "left">
            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_17.jpg"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Ultimate_Frisbee%2C_Jul_2009_-_19.jpg" alt="Creative Common Ultimate Photo" title="By Ed Yourdon [CC BY-SA 2.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0)], via Wikimedia Commons"/> </a>

            <a href="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AUltimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"><img alt="Ultimate Frisbee Colorado Cup 2005" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7d/Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg/512px-Ultimate_Frisbee_Colorado_Cup_2005.jpg"/></a>


            <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/paradisecoastie/15409853738/" title="Ultimate Frisbee"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3948/15409853738_7dbfbfbac7_k.jpg"  alt="Ultimate Frisbee"></a>
        </aside>
        <section class = "right">

    <h2>Background</h2>
    <p>Ultimate Frisbee/Ultimate has been around in some fashion since the 1960s.  Joel Silver is credited with introducing the game to his high school in 1968 after learning about the game at summer camp.  The game spread to more college campuses soon afterward.</p>
    <p>The Ultimate Players Association was founded in 1979 and began organizing touraments across the country.  In 2010, UPA because the <a href = "htpp://http://www.usaultimate.org/index.html">USA Ultimate</a>.</p>
    <p>Other than professional tournaments, games of Ultimate are typically played without referess.  Instead, players rely on "The Spirit of the Game" to encourage sportsmanship and self-officiating.</p>
    <h2>Sources</h2>



<ul>
        <li><a href = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_(sport)">Ultimate (sport)</a></li>
        <li><a href = "http://www.wfdf.org/">World Flying Disc Federation</a></li>
    </ul>
    </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The required output [link] http://www.intro-webdesign.com/CSS/assignment-2/index.jpg

Comment: note: you have body  { padding : 20pxpx; } in your css

Comment: Removing the padding did't help